# Excel year-week combination calculation

Tags: vba, date, excel, formula

I am currently making an excel model where the date is an important aspect of it. However as the information comes from a different source it is sometimes structured in such a way that it is not realistic. 
I have a problem with the calculation of the year and week combination when adding weeks or subtracting them. 
The start data looks like this:

```
yyyyww (example: 201525, year 2015 week 25)
```

Now if I want to add for example 3 weeks, I can just do that by adding 3, results is 201528. However when it comes to 201552 (and sometimes yyyy53) it is more difficult as I need to calculate to 2016.

The same goes for when calculating back in the time, towards 2014 or lower. Does anyone know or have a solution for this? Maybe in VBA? or a formula trick?

Comment: what is your current formula?

Comment: I currently am only adding and subtracting but then it results in things like 201567 (year 2015 and week 67), which of course does not exist.

Comment: the week between `201452` and `201502` is called `201453` or `201501` for you?

Comment: I am thinking it would be easier to actually convert that to a date that excel understands and then manipulate it as you need.  Then you can convert it back to yyyyww

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a formula to add 1 to your week number format looks like this:

```
=YEAR(DATE(LEFT(A2, 4), 1, 1) + MID(A2, 5, 2) * 7) * 100 +
 WEEKNUM(DATE(LEFT(A2, 4), 1, 1) + MID(A2, 5, 2) * 7)
```

it will create a sequence of week numbers that includes: `201452` => `201453` => `201502`

- `LEFT(A2, 4)` and `MID(A2, 5, 2)` extract the year and week components
- `date(year, 1, 1) + (week - 1) * 7` converts that to an actual Excel Date value, 
   e.g. `201502` => `2015-01-08`
- `date(year, 1, 1) + week * 7` will create a date that is 1 week after the "current" date
- `year(date) * 100 + weeknum(date)` converts that date back to `yyyyww` format

Comment: Thank you very much. How come it skips the 201501 though?

Comment: `201501` is the same week as `201453` (1.1.2015 was a Thursday)